# How to apply row hover elevation effect on mat-table sticky column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm implementing a `mat-table` component where rows have the following style when hovering over them:

```css
.mat-row:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    @include mat-elevation(6);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

The table also has the `sticky` property applied to the first column of the table:

```html
<mat-table>
     <!-- First Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="first" sticky>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> First </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> Some data </td>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

The issue I'm facing is that the `hover` effect for the row doesn't apply to the stickied column. Instead it just applies to the row while leaving the stickied column without any applied effect.

[Table rows with hover effect and what it looks like on the stickied column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2bpx.png)

What I've tried so far is targeting the `mat-table-sticky` class directly with the same on hover effect as the row one has to no avail. I've also tried wrapping the stickied `mat-cell` in another div and making that div have the hover effect which also did nothing. No matter what I try I still get the same result which is in the above screenshot. Any help would be greately appriciated.

Comment: are you of using which version of angular and angular-material ?

Comment: Using version 11

Comment: and both are at same version ?